# Exclude results from Directory.GetFiles

Tags: c#, .net

If I want to call [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx) and have it return all files that match the pattern `*.bin` but I want to exclude all of the files that would match the pattern `LOG#.bin` where `#` is a running counter of indeterminate length. Is there a way to filter out the results at the step of passing in a search filter to `GetFiles` or must I get the result array then remove the items that I want to exclude?

Comment: `Directory.GetFiles` doesn't have this ability. The pattern parameter only indicates what *should* be included. A better option would probably be to use `Directory.EnumerateFiles` and specify a `Where` clause on its result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use Linq, [`Directory.EnumerateFiles()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles.aspx) and a `Where()` filter - that way you only end up with the files you want, the rest is filtered out.

Something like this should work:

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"^LOG\d+.bin$");
var logFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(somePath, "*.bin")
                        .Where(f => !re.IsMatch(Path.GetFileName(f)))
                        .ToList();
```

As pointed out `Directory.EnumerateFiles` requires .NET 4.0. Also a somewhat cleaner solution (at the cost of a little more overhead) is using  `DirectoryInfo` / `EnumerateFiles()` which returns an `IEnumerable<FileInfo>` so you have direct access to the file name and the extension without further parsing.

Comment: If you need to use .Net < 4.0 then you can use Pinvoke to achieve a similar result. Check out: http://tom-shelton.net/index.php/2010/01/02/using-extension-methods-and-the-win32-api-to-efficiently-enumerate-the-file-system/

Comment: Thanks I knew about the `.Where` clause, I just wanted to know if it could be done without that second filter. I made a small change to your code as it have matched something like `ThisIsNotALOG0.bin` which I would want it to match. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

There is a solution using Linq:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace getfilesFilter
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\temp", "*.bin").Select(p => Path.GetFileName(p)).Where(p => p.StartsWith("LOG"));
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(file);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```